# Numbers that have constant digits value independent of base

Tags: number-systems

I was wondering why for example $\dfrac{1111_b \cdot 111_b}{11_b \cdot 1_b} = 11211_b$. Is there a good explanation for this and is there a name for products like this which have constant digits value independent of base? It also seems to hold with $\dfrac{11111_b \cdot 1111_b \cdot 111_b}{111_b \cdot 11_b \cdot 1_b}$ and other numbers as well.

Here is my general question:

> Prove that $$R(m,k) = \frac{ 1^{(m)}_b \cdot 1^{(m-1)}_b\cdots 1^{(m-k+1)}_b}{1^{(1)}_b \cdot 1^{(2)}_b\cdots 1^{(k)}_b} = c_b$$ where $c$ is a constant and $b>2$.

Comment: The digit 2 does not exist in binary.

Comment: @mathreadler For any base other than $2$.

Comment: @Puzzled417, Write $$1111_b$$  as $$1+b+b^2+b^3$$ etc.

Comment: Typo in the numerator with $111_b$?

Answer (score 1):

This is because multiplication in a [number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) becomes a special type of [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) with carry. If the digits involved are small enough compared to the base used, then carry will never happen and we can calculate expressions like yours for example as a sequence of polynomial multiplications and divisions.

---

For example the first one: $1111_b$ can first be divided by $11_b$ to produce $101_b$, then the multiplication will be $111_b + 100_b\cdot 111_b = 11211_b$

Comment: In fact, the generalization is in terms of repunits. Let $$R(m,k) = \frac{ 1^{(m)}_b \cdot 1^{(m-1)}_b\cdots 1^{(m-k+1)}_b}{1^{(1)}_b \cdot 1^{(2)}_b\cdots 1^{(k)}_b} = c_b$$ where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: Yes but it will work for arbitrary polynomials if we ensure the coefficients are not too large. Arbitrary polynomials are more general than products and quotients of repunits.

Comment: Can you prove it in the case of the repunits?

Comment: That was not your original question.